# Static Routes in Custom Fields in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm working on a custom field used to pick datetimes in Yesod (stored as UTCTime). It uses [Trent Richardson's timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). I actually have it working already. The only problem is that I have the static route to the javascript file in a handler instead of in the custom field. When I move it to the custom field, I get errors. A portion of the code (largely copied from yesod.form.fields) is below:

```
jqueryDateTimeField :: (RenderMessage site FormMessage, YesodJquery site) => JqueryDaySettings -> Field (HandlerT site IO) UTCTime
jqueryDateTimeField jds = Field
{
    fieldParse = parseHelper $ maybe (Left MsgInvalidDay) Right . readUTC . unpack
  , fieldView = \theId name attrs val isReq -> do
        toWidget [shamlet|
$newline never
<input id="#{theId}" name="#{name}" *{attrs} type="text" :isReq:required="" value="#{showVal val}">
|]
        addScript' urlJqueryJs
        addScript' urlJqueryUiJs
        addScript $ StaticR js_jquery_ui_timepicker_addon_js -- Bad line here
        addStylesheet' urlJqueryUiCss    --error seems to occurs on the line below
        toWidget [julius|
$(function(){
var i = document.getElementById("#{rawJS theId}");
$(i).datetimepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth:#{jsBool $ jdsChangeMonth jds},
    changeYear:#{jsBool $ jdsChangeYear jds},
    numberOfMonths:#{rawJS $ mos $ jdsNumberOfMonths jds},
    yearRange:#{toJSON $ jdsYearRange jds}
});
});
|]
  , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
}
```

The line that says `addScript $ StaticR js_jquery_ui_timepicker_addon_js` is what's causing problems. I know this because when I put that line in the handler that calls this field, it works. I get an error message saying

```
DateTime.hs:73:13:
Could not deduce (site ~ App)
from the context (RenderMessage site FormMessage, YesodJquery site)
  bound by the type signature for
             jqueryDateTimeField :: (RenderMessage site FormMessage,
                                     YesodJquery site) =>
                                    JqueryDaySettings -> Field (HandlerT site IO) UTCTime
```

It goes on, but what bothers me is that the error seems to occur on the wrong line. Line 73 is the one that starts with `toWidget`. So, my question is, how can you use a static route in a custom field? Please let me know if there is more information I should provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because your `jqueryDateTimeField` is generic, i.e., it'll work with any Yesod site that satisfies the given constraints<sup>1</sup>, but your `StaticR` refers to a route constructor defined specifically for your site, which is represented by the `App` data type (defined in `Foundation.hs`). The error `Could not deduce (site ~ App)` means that given your use of `StaticR`, the compiler expects `site` to be the same as `App` always, but your other constraints do not confirm it for the compiler.

One solution to this is simply to make `jqueryDateTimeField` specific to your site by changing the type signature to:

```
jqueryDateTimeField :: JqueryDaySettings -> Field Handler UTCTime
```

Note that `Handler` is a type synonym for `HandlerT App IO` — the handler for your site.

While that will work, a better solution is to use `YesodJquery`'s `urlJqueryUiDateTimePicker` function to get the URL for the date-time picker add-on and adding that as a script. `urlJqueryUiDateTimePicker` accepts the object representing your site (an `App` object in this case) and returns `Either (Route site) Text` — either a route under your site or a text based URL — pointing to the javascript file. You can add that as a script in `jqueryDateTimeField` using [`addScriptEither`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/latest/doc/html/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#v%3aaddScriptEither).
Then, you can change `App`'s `YesodJquery` instance to return your static route.

So, replace `addScript $ StaticR js_jquery_ui_timepicker_addon_js` with:

```
app <- getYesod   -- This gets your App object
addScriptEither (urlJqueryUiDateTimePicker app)
```

And change the `urlJqueryUiDateTimePicker` method in `App`'s `YesodJquery` instance to return the route you want to use:

```
instance YesodJquery App where
    urlJqueryUiDateTimePicker _ = Left $ StaticR js_jquery_ui_timepicker_addon_js
```

---

<sup>1</sup> 
In the original type signature, the handler was represented by `HandlerT site IO` where `site` satisfies the constraints `RenderMessage site FormMessage` and `YesodJquery site`.
`RenderMessage site FormMessage` requires that `site` must know how to generate messages from the [`FormMessage`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/1.3.1/doc/html/Yesod-Form-Types.html#t%3aFormMessage) data type.
`YesodJquery site` requires that the site must have access to static files for jQuery, jQuery UI, and the jQuery UI date-time picker add-on ([see here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/1.3.1/doc/html/Yesod-Form-Jquery.html)).